disabling ssr using static export
I came to realize that I didn't quite require most SSR features that nextjs provided, and would be more cost effective for me to host my app through a cdn, and I was delighted to find researching on how to switch to traditional SPAs without ssrs, that nextjs supported static exports that did this.
But, can this be configured also for development? Since, I would like to get the same behavioral experience to the static export during development and face similar issues I would otherwise have only in production(e.g. hydration errors would then appear). Is it possible to switch this on for development as well? i.e. npm run dev would launch the next's static export mode?

I found this with a quick search: https://gist.github.com/gaearon/9d6b8eddc7f5e647a054d7b333434ef6 it doesn't seem to be possible

@user3791775 , also, the thread mentions using export as such may cause some problem for dynamic routes I guess... manual maintenance?

I think you can build it as a static site, then you can also host it without nodejs: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/static-site-generation
